# How to add a class on a dynamic range of elements - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make`Date Range Picker` similar to [**this**](http://www.daterangepicker.com/#ex2).

I've tried using things like

```
     $('#calendar-dates').on('mouseover', 'td', function() {
         if($(this).html() > window.start){
          $(this).addClass("added");
        }
     });

      $('#calendar-dates').on('click', 'td', function() {
        window.start = $(this).html(); // get the number of the day

        $(this).addClass("start"); // to mark it the date-selection start

      });
```

What I want is if I go `horizontally` with the mouse button over the `td` elements that come after `this day`, to highlight them with a `background-color`

OR

if I go `vertically` to change the `background-color` of the previous row.

I have read about `slice` but I can't think to understand how to utilize it properly.

Also using `mouseover`, after a point it stops highlighting elements.

Please help.

Comment: what is window.start here?

Comment: a global variable that holds the value of the starting day of the range.

Comment: Well, since you have a working example already, why not learn the concept of what you might do from that? Go to the github page, find the `daterangepicker.js` file, and search for `//highlight the dates`, and there you have it. It is always good to learn from existing code, even though you will not want to just copy that.

Comment: i did that but it seems a bit complicated without knowing the whole code from the tips of my hand.

Answer (score -1):

you can try this.

```
$( "#calendar-dates" ).mouseover(function() {
       // do something 
}).click(function() {
      // do something 
});
```

Comment: thanks but this does not help with what i am trying to achieve.